# Parameter pack used for default template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'd like to do something like this:

```
template<int... myints>
struct A
{}

template<int... myints, class traits = A<myints...>>
struct B
{}
```

I know that parameter packs should appear only at the end, but I remember there are some exceptions. Do you think that is there a way to make this code (or something similar) work?

Thanks

Comment: why that downvote??

Comment: Suppose you didn't want the default `traits`.  How do you envision replacing it? Is that impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

- wrap the types into tuples.
- use specialisation to convert type lists to types

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<int...myints> struct A {};

namespace detail {
    template<class Sequence>
    struct make_A_from;

    template<class T, T...ts>
    struct make_A_from<std::integer_sequence<T, ts...>> {
        using type = A<ts...>;
    };
}
template<class Sequence> using make_A_from = typename detail::make_A_from<Sequence>::type;

template<class Sequence, class TraitsTuple = make_A_from<Sequence> >
struct B;

template<typename Int, Int...myints, class Traits> 
struct B<std::integer_sequence<Int, myints...>, Traits>
{
    using ints_tuple = std::tuple<std::integral_constant<Int, myints>...>;
    using traits_type = Traits;
};

namespace detail {
    template<typename Int, Int...is>
    struct make_B
    {
        using type = B<std::integer_sequence<Int, is...>>;
    };
}

template<int...is> using make_B = B<std::integer_sequence<int, is...>>;

int main()
{
    make_B<1,3,4,5> b;
    B<std::integer_sequence<int, 5,6,7,8>> b2;
    B<std::integer_sequence<int, 5,6,7,8>, class CustomTrait> b3;
}
```

Comment: interesting solution

Comment: `myints` are supposed to be `int...` non-type literals, not types.

Comment: @Yakk oops - will revisit

Comment: @Yakk fixed. Thank you.

Comment: I'd use `std::integer_sequence` if you had C++14.  As an aside, `template<int...is> using ints=std::tuple<std::integral_constant<int, is>...>;` would also be useful here.

Comment: @Yakk yes, I thought about that but `integer_sequence` has no `std::get<>` overloads (why??), so it seems to me that `tuple<integral_constant...>` is more useful.

Comment: @Yakk   richard hodges,  I've tried to use that code with something like: B<1,2,3,4,5> b; but it doesn't compile. No possibilities to make it work in this way?

Comment: @user3770392 Parameter packs consume everything until the end.  Everything.  So how would you change the type *after* the pack?

Comment: @Yakk  so how would you use that code? how about using two parameters packs?

Comment: @Yakk don't know what I was thinking when I posted the previous answer. I must have been tired. Updated and corrected.

Comment: @RichardHodges So, `integer_sequence` is C++14, and the question is C++11; the comment about integer sequence wasn't "replace" but rather "mention alternative with C++14"; if you want to make it C++11, you'd have to write integer sequence first (which admittedly is easy)

Comment: @Yakk oh you're right. I haven't written c++11 since c++14 came out. I mean, who would? There are no compilers that support the one and not the other.